# Log index of array where condition is true (has as many 0s together)

Tags: javascript

As part of something I'm working on, I'm trying to get my function to, for now, log when it finds the first instance of the longest 0s in a row - for example:

```
holLength([1,1,0,1,0,0,1]); // starts at index 4
holLength([0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]); // starts at index 3
holLength([1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]); // starts at index 1
holLength([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]); // starts at index 1
holLength([1,0,0,1,0,0,1]); // starts at index 1
    holLength([0,0,1,1,1,0,1]); // starts at index 0, and is WRONG
holLength([0,1,1,0,0,1,1]); // starts at index 3
```

I can't get the `holLength([0,0,1,1,1,0,1]);` to work as `changeCount` needs to initially have a value of -1, otherwise the other tests fail.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Ideally I want it to state the index where there are more 1s in a row after the 0s finish, e.g.:

```
holLength([1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]); // starts at index 4
holLength([1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]); // starts at index 1
```

But it's probably simpler to fix the first part first! Any help and best coding practices suggestions would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

The code:

```js
function holLength(arr) {
 if(!(arr.includes(0) && arr.includes(1) && arr.join('').includes('01'))) {
  throw new RangeError('Bad Input - Function Aborted');
 } else {
  var oneIndexes = [], zeroIndexes = [], longest1s = 0, longest0s = 0, zeros = 0, ones = 0, len = arr.length, holStart = 0, changeCount = -1, first1 = 0, nextOnes = 0;

  createIndexes();
  console.log('zeroIndexes: ' + zeroIndexes + '\noneIndexes: ' + oneIndexes);

  for(i = 0; i < zeroIndexes.length; i++) { // for each zero indexes in arr
   console.log('Arr Index: ' + zeroIndexes[i] + ', arr[i]: ' + arr[i]);
   for(j = arr[zeroIndexes[i]]; j < len; j++) { // go through each 0 value
    let next = arr[j+1];
    let current = arr[j];
    let thisIndex = zeroIndexes[i];
    let nextIndex = zeroIndexes[i+1];

    if(thisIndex === 0 && current === 0) {
     zeros++;
     // changeCount++;
    } else if (thisIndex === 0 && current === 1) {
     ones++;
    }
    if(next === 0 && nextIndex !== len) { // if next original array value = 0 & not last one
     zeros++;
     ones = 0;
     if (zeros > longest0s) {
      longest0s = zeros;
      console.log('j: ' + j + ', longest0s changed. Changed from index ' + (j - changeCount) + '. changeCount: ' + changeCount);
      changeCount++;
      holStart = (j - changeCount + 1);
     }
     console.log('   zeros: ' + zeros + ', longest0s: ' + longest0s + ', j: ' + j);
    } else if (next === 1 && nextIndex !== len) { // if 1 & not last
     ones++;
     zeros = 0;
     if (ones > longest1s) {
      longest1s = ones;
      console.log('longest1s changed. Changed from index ' + j); // wrong? cant be j?
     }
     console.log('   ones: ' + ones + ', longest1s: ' + longest1s + ', j: ' + j);
    }
   }
   console.log('==========');
  }
  first1 = holStart + longest0s;
  console.log('first1: ' + first1);
  console.log('hol starts at index: ' + holStart + ' for ' + longest0s + ' days in the north');

  // for loop - use while instead?
  for (i = first1; i < len; i++) {
   let next = arr[i+1];
   let nextIndex = zeroIndexes[i+1];

   if (next === 1 && nextIndex !== len) {
    nextOnes++;
    console.log('nextOnes: ' + nextOnes);
   }
  }

  // ===== FUNCTIONS =====
  function createIndexes() {
   for(i = 0; i < len; i++) { // add all 0 & 1 indexes into arrays
    pushIndexes(i, 0);
    pushIndexes(i, 1);
   }
  }
  function pushIndexes(i, no) {
   if (no === 1 && arr[i] === no) {
    oneIndexes.push(i);
   }
   if (no === 0 && arr[i] === no) {
    zeroIndexes.push(i);
   }
  }
 return (longest0s + nextOnes);
 }
}
console.log(holLength([1,1,0,1,0,0,1])); // starts at index 4
console.log(holLength([0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0])); // starts at index 3
console.log(holLength([1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1])); // starts at index 1
console.log(holLength([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1])); // starts at index 1
console.log(holLength([1,0,0,1,0,0,1])); // starts at index 1
console.log(holLength([0,0,1,1,1,0,1])); // starts at index 0, and is WRONG
console.log(holLength([0,1,1,0,0,1,1])); // starts at index 3
```

Comment: please add some information to this part *"Ideally I want it to state the index where there are more 1s in a row after the 0s finish"* and how the given (last two)examples match it.

Comment: @NinaScholz   He's given two example -> The first `1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1`,.  it's index 4, because `0,0,1,1` has more 1's, than `0,0,1` following the `0,0`,.. that's how I've interpreted it anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the logic from "how many zeros / ones are in a row" to "how many equal values are in a row" it gets way more easy:

```
 function occurences(array) {
    const counts = {}, max = {};
    let count = 0, start = 0, current = array[0];
    for(const [index, el] of array.entries()) {
       if(el === current) {
         count++;
       } else {
          (counts[current] || (counts[current] = [])).push({ count, start, end: index - 1});
          if(!max[current] || count > max[current].count) max[current] = { start, count, end: index - 1 };
          count = 1; current = el, start = index;
       }
   }

   return { count, max };
}
```

So you can use it as:

```
 const result = occurences([1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]);

 console.log(
   result.max[0].start, // start position of the maximum 0 row
   result.max[1].count // maximum number of ones in a row
 );
```

Comment: I assume you have skipped this bit for now -> `there are more 1s in a row after the 0s finish`

Comment: @keith I'm not sure what he means there, for all testcases it returns the right result.

Comment: `for all testcases it returns the right result`,   It's hard to tell, for some reason you never created this as a snippet,.. I'm sure you normally do too, any reason?.

Comment: @keith no i don't. 1) im on mobile 2) I usually do testing in production ;)

Comment: Mobile!!, yeah shame we can't snippet.. But I've just tested with `[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]`, and it return `1,1`, instead of `4,2`.. @user8758206  Could you confirm, as that's a different result to what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is keep a track of your best option,.
Javascript Object literals are great here.

Here I keep track of how many 0's, and then how many 1's come after it.  Then inside the loop I check to see if it's better than the `best`.

Here is an example..

```js
function holLength(arr) {
  let best;
  for (let start = 0; start < arr.length; start ++) {
    if (arr[start] !== 0) continue;
    let c;
    for (c = start; c < arr.length; c ++) {
      if (arr[c] !== 0) break;
    }
    const len = c - start;
    let ones = 0;
    for (; c < arr.length; c ++) {
      if (arr[c] !== 1) break;
      ones ++;
    }
    if (!best ||
        len > best.len ||
        (len === best.len && ones > best.ones)) 
    {
      best = {len, ones, start};      
    }
  }
  return best;
}


const ret = [
  holLength([1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]), // starts at index 4
  holLength([1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]) // starts at index 1
];

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the temporary result and iterate the array while checking the value. If a truthy value is found, check, update and reset the counter. Otherwise check the counter and take the index for later storing.

At the end return the index.

```js
function holLength(array) {
    var result = { count: 0 },
        count = 0,
        index;
        
    array.forEach((v, i) => {
        if (v) {
            if (result.count < count) {
                result = { index, count };
            }
            count = 0;                
            return;
        }
        if (!count) {
            index = i;
        }
        count++;
    });
    return result.index;
}

console.log(holLength([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])); // starts at index 4
console.log(holLength([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])); // starts at index 3
console.log(holLength([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])); // starts at index 1
console.log(holLength([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])); // starts at index 1
console.log(holLength([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])); // starts at index 1
console.log(holLength([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])); // starts at index 0, and is WRONG
console.log(holLength([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])); // starts at index 3
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Approach with counting ones at the beginning first for a given index.

```js
function holLength(array) {
    var result = { count: 0 },
        count = 0,
        index,
        ones = array
            .slice()
            .reverse()
            .map((s => v => s = v && s + 1)(0))
            .reverse();

    array.forEach((v, i) => {
        if (v) {
            if (result.count < count && ones[i] >= count) {
                result = { index, count };
            }
            count = 0;                
            return;
        }
        if (!count++) {
            index = i;
        }
    });
    return result.index;
}

console.log(holLength([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])); // starts at index 4
console.log(holLength([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])); // starts at index 1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I know the OP said -> `But it's probably simpler to fix the first part first!`,  but to be honest it makes sense doing both,.. Your second to last is not returning `4`.

Comment: @Keith, the both groups does not fit together, but the second with counting ones wotks now with a different approach by using an object with the count for a specific index.